# What is the alternative of numpy.newaxis in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

Hi I am new to tensorflow. I want to implement the following python code in tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0])
print(a) ## [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0]
print(a.shape) ## (9,)
b = a[:, np.newaxis] ### want to write this in tensorflow.
print(b.shape) ## (9,1)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that would be [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) -

```
tf.expand_dims(a, 1) # Or tf.expand_dims(a, -1)
```

Basically, we list the axis ID where this new axis is to be inserted and the trailing axes/dims are *pushed-back*.

From the linked docs, here's few examples of expanding dimensions -

```
# 't' is a tensor of shape [2]
shape(expand_dims(t, 0)) ==> [1, 2]
shape(expand_dims(t, 1)) ==> [2, 1]
shape(expand_dims(t, -1)) ==> [2, 1]

# 't2' is a tensor of shape [2, 3, 5]
shape(expand_dims(t2, 0)) ==> [1, 2, 3, 5]
shape(expand_dims(t2, 2)) ==> [2, 3, 1, 5]
shape(expand_dims(t2, 3)) ==> [2, 3, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 20):

The corresponding command is `tf.newaxis` (or `None`, as in numpy). It does not have an entry on its own in tensorflow's documentation, but is briefly mentioned on the doc page of [`tf.stride_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice).

```
x = tf.ones((10,10,10))
y = x[:, tf.newaxis] # or y = x [:, None]
print(y.shape)
# prints (10, 1, 10, 10)
```

Using `tf.expand_dims` is fine too but, as stated in the link above,

> Those interfaces are much more friendly, and highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a[..., tf.newaxis].astype("float32")
```

This Works as well

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in exactly the same type(i.e. `None`) as in NumPy, then `tf.newaxis` is the exact alternative to `np.newaxis`.

Example:

```
In [71]: a1 = tf.constant([2,2], name="a1")

In [72]: a1
Out[72]: <tf.Tensor 'a1_5:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>

# add a new dimension
In [73]: a1_new = a1[tf.newaxis, :]

In [74]: a1_new
Out[74]: <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_5:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=int32>

# add one more dimension
In [75]: a1_new = a1[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]

In [76]: a1_new
Out[76]: <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_6:0' shape=(1, 2, 1) dtype=int32>
```

This is exactly the same kind of operations that you do in NumPy. Just use it exactly at the same dimension where you want it to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [tf.keras.layers.Reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape):

```py
# as first layer in a Sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((3, 4), input_shape=(12,)))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 4)
# note: `None` is the batch dimension

# as intermediate layer in a Sequential model
model.add(Reshape((6, 2)))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 6, 2)

# also supports shape inference using `-1` as dimension
model.add(Reshape((-1, 2, 2)))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 2, 2)
```